# AmCharts Value Axis

Tags: amcharts

In AmCharts, how do you predefine the maximum and minimum scales of a value axis, but still let the graph calculate a new maximum and minimum scale if the values on the graph exceed these values?

I am plotting very small changes in values and I do not want the scale too low, if I set the scale and the values exceed this number, I want the graph to auto scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible out of the box. The valueAxis `maximum` and `minimum` will stick to the values you provided if set, regardless of whether the new values exceed those boundaries. Your only option is to unset or set new values for those properties when the new values exceed your boundaries. Unsetting the properties (setting them to undefined) and calling `validateData` or `validateNow` afterward will make the chart auto-scale again.

For example:

```
//<data update omitted>
//you'll likely want some logic to determine when modify to the max/min
chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = undefined; //reset to default behavior
chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = <new value>; //set new minimum
chart.validateData(); //redraw everything
```

Comment: This solved the first issue, now I have a problem when I zoom on the graph using chartCursor. Once I zoom the scales on the graph are reset and I am no longer able to view my data. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Can you post a working jsfiddle of your code that reproduces this?